# How to mock differnent for same func?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Here is a code I want to test

```
if os.path.exist(path_one):
    func1()

elif os.path.exist(path_two):
    func2()
```

While writing unittest. I want to

1. mock the first os.path.exist return Flase so func1 do not execute
2. mock the second os.path.exist return True so func2 will execute

But I did not find a way to mock different return for the same func os.path.exist

One way is to wrap it into different func and mock. But I do not want to do this just because for unittest. Any good idea?

Comment: Use a queue and have your mock dequeue the values you want to return.

Comment: @JohnH genius, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [patch()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) method with `side_effect`.

> A function to be called whenever the Mock is called. See the side_effect attribute. Useful for raising exceptions or dynamically changing return values.

E.g.

`main.py`:

```py
import os


def func1():
    print('func1')


def func2():
    print('func2')


def main():
    path_one = 'path_one'
    path_two = 'path_two'

    if os.path.exists(path_one):
        func1()

    elif os.path.exists(path_two):
        func2()
```

`test_main.py`:

```py
from main import main
from unittest import TestCase, mock
import unittest


class TestMain(TestCase):
    @mock.patch('main.os.path.exists')
    def test_main(self, mock_exists):
        def side_effect(path):
            if(path == 'path_one'):
                return False
            if(path == 'path_two'):
                return True

        mock_exists.side_effect = side_effect
        main()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

test result:

```
func2
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```